Test report for assertj tests
at the moment I have some test running, using assertj and they are passing. The test report I can generate in Intellij, has no content except for setup stuff etc. That is as expected, but I would like the report to have a list of the assertions made, verbosely, so that a co-worker can read what was tested. How can I set that up ?
So far I looked at the objects the assertions returned, to find clues as to what could be the setting I need.

Have a look at the description consumer which can help you build a report of assertion descriptions (you have to set the description though) https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-assertion-description-consumer

Ok, that would give me a customisable description. Lets say I have a list and Im checking if an object exists in the list, using some of the fields. I would like to add to the report what was compared and maybe I dont know which index in the list was the match. In the report it should say: Object X was compared to Object Y, including the fields that were compared and their content, so that someone can read it very literally.  Im using assertThat and isIn.

that information is not available in the description but in the assertion error, you can get a report of errors if you use soft assertions which collects them (but on a test by test basis), probably not meeting your needs but that the closest AssertJ can do at the moment.
